# How can I test the new feature AirDrop with only one iPhone / iPad?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop

I am using UIActivityViewController to share data between devices using AirDrop but the problem is I can't test the feature because I have just one device that supports AirDrop.
Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Airdrop "drops" stuff between two devices (iOS 7).

Answer (score 5):

No, there literally isn't. You **have** to have another device, I also looked into this earlier.

Comment: It looks like the iOS Simulator doesn't support AirDrop either.

Answer (score 5):

You need at least two devices to test the `Airdrop` functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Right. You must have 2 fairly recent devices. The iPhone 4s does not support AirDrop for some reason, while the iPad Mini does.

Answer (score 0):

The way Hegarty does it for the Trax demo (Stanford cs193p) is he runs the demo onto his phone. AirDrop on the Mac then sees his phone and he drops the .gpx file there. The app running on the phone will get the message and read the file.